# How to check Intel iGPU frequency on Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel, intel-graphics, overclocking

I own Intel Haswell G3420. At stock its iGPU has 1,15 GHz turbo frequency. In my UEFI I overclocked the iGPU to 1,5 GHz and added voltage. However the framerates in both benchmarks and games are the same after the OC. I once read that Intel iGPU OC doesn't work on Linux because of some problems with turbo boost in Linux kernel. I want to check if the frequency while gaming hits 1,5 Ghz or if it stays unchanged at 1,15 GHz. So I need a way to check current Intel iGPU frequency. I know that Nvidia binary drivers are capable of that, however I have no idea how can I check it using Intel iGPU.

TL;DR

How can I check Intel iGPU current frequency on Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `lshw`. If you don't have it installed, install it with `sudo yum install lshw` (Redhat/Fedora/CentOS) or `sudo apt-get install lshw` (Debian/Ubuntu/etc).

```
lshw -c display
```

On one of my (old) machines, it outputs:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: K8M800/K8N800/K8N800A [S3 UniChrome Pro]
       vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm agp agp-3.0 vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=32 mingnt=2
       resources: memory:f0000000-f3ffffff memory:f4000000-f4ffffff memory:f5000000-f500ffff
```

The 4th line up from the bottom has the clock speed information.

**EDIT**
Then again, that doesn't make sense...only 66MHz?? Perhaps [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/5417) [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/5419) would help...

Comment: How is «this answer» supposed to help if the author explicitly saying that they not aware of such a tool for Intel GPU?

Comment: @Hi-Angel When I posted this answer, no-one had told me that `lshw` did not work for Intel GPU's. If you would like me to delete it, I can.

Comment: No, I am not talking about `lshw`. By this «this answer» I meant the link to another answer below the **EDIT**.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I linked to that answer because it seems that the author of that answer has more information than I do. He is aware of `lshw`, and knows that it doesn't do the job. And he does *not* know of anything for Intel GPU's, therefore he is a better source of information than I am. The conclusion: This can't be done for Intel GPU's.

Comment: The author said just what they said: they does not know of anything for Intel GPUs. No more. Unknowledge can never be a proof.

Comment: The `UNCLAIMED` in the output means that lshw didn't recognise the device, so it's just showing generic PCI bus info. 66MHz is the PCI clock speed.